# Authentication - asp mvc area issue on routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I again have problem with routing :)
When I run application if user is not authenticated he is redirected to login page. 
I use `FormsAuthentication`
Login page is in area Account
Current URL is

```
http://localhost:38962/Account/Home/Index?ReturnUrl=%2f
```

Setup from web config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Home/Index" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

I have tried to set route in AccountAreaRegistration class

```
context.MapRoute("home_login",
                "",
                new { area = "Account", controller = "Home", action = "Index", ReturnUrl = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

and a few others setup bu can't get login page and to URL stays just

```
http://localhost:38962
```

And I also have route in AccountAreaRegister

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Account_default",
                "Account/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**Update 1**

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default",
                    "{controller}/{action}/{cityId}",
                    new { area = "MainArea", controller = "Home", action = "Index", cityId = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    new string[] { "MCN.WebUI.Areas.MainArea.Controllers" }).DataTokens.Add("area", "MainArea");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your MapRoute function call, second parameter should be

```
Account/{controller}/{action}
```

remove the area in the third parameter

**web.config**

```
 <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Comment: It's still same. I don't know if this is important. In global.asax I have default route that direct user to page in another area. This page requires authentication (controller has Authorize attribute). If user is not authenticated that this login page is started with this whole url.

Comment: can you post that code?  And also did you enable authorization in web.config?

Comment: that route shouldn't cause any problems.. are you sure you enabled authorization in web.config?

Comment: I don't have authorization in web config. Is that important for routing?

Comment: Can you try creating a sample default mvc projct and add Account and Main Areas and set the config and try?  There is no reason for this not working

Comment: I have just created default asp mvc project and added a route for logon and it works fine. But I add authorization in web.config and suddenly url becomes: http://localhost:50927/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f

Comment: may be your forgot to change the loginUrl value to ~/Account/Home/Index?

Comment: When I create asp.mvc template project login url in web config is ~/Account/LogOn.

Comment: Hah I have made what you suggest. And I removed authorization from web config and it worked :)